# C# : Is there any C# function to insert primary key from one table into another

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables in which i want to insert data one after another. The primary key of first table is in the 2nd. Is there any C# function so that i can insert the primary key of first table into another at 1 go, without any select query?

Comment: What is the type of the primary key column?

Comment: datatype of primary key is int

Comment: Sounds like you need a stored procedure, instead of a C# function.  Or possibly set up a trigger on your first table.

Comment: i was thinking to avoid select

Comment: @DaveMarkle: yup - you got me there! :-) You'll get some information from SQL Server without even using a `SELECT` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it with a stored procedure that performs both inserts and returns the identity value to the caller.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id int;

    INSERT INTO [table1] (col1) VALUES ('Foo');
    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    INSERT INTO [table2] (col1, col2) VALUES (@id, 'Bar');

    RETURN @id;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You might look at using the OUTPUT clause in your insert statment.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand your question but I think you want to know the primary key without consulting the server.

It this case you need to use guid's as the primary key which can be generated client side in C#. Identity columns won't work as they are generated by sql server.

Or you you could create a stored procedure that does the insert for you at the server and leave the identities at the client empty.

**Update 1**

To get the latest generated identity from sql server you can use

```
SCOPE_IDENTITY
```

(This is equivalent to mysql_insert_id() )

There are some other options namely

- @@IDENTITY
- SCOPE_IDENTITY()
- IDENT_CURRENT

Which you can read up on at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: Actually you can do that without guids if you use number pools with client side generation. Thigns aer not black and white and there is a world of smart things people have dreamed up with the last years. Like pulling a "block number" and then allocating the lower 2-3 digits yourself.

Comment: i wanted to know if there is a function like mysql_insert_id() as in php

Comment: @user1419919 Thats possible with SQL Server, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @TomTom Sure you can get clever if required but lets suggest the most simple thing that works if there is no extra requirement. GUIDs may look not pretty to some (that's subjective) but it reduces complexity considerably.

Comment: @TomTom In SQL server 2012 there is the new concept of SEQUENCE which I believe can help here if a number is required. Haven't tried it out myself yet though.

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` is not guaranteed to return the last value in the same scope. You should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead.

Comment: and ident_current should NEVER be used for this. It is not limited to the scope you are in and can return an identity from someone else's query running at the same time. It is the cause of many many data integrity issues.